# NetSuite Eclipse update site workaround?

Tags: netsuite

The Eclipse update site shown on NetSuite help no longer appears to work ( http://system.​netsuite.​com/​download/​ide/​update_​e4 ) Does anyone have a work around in order to install the NetSuite eclipse IDE plugin?

Here's the error message shown in Eclipse: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException: Unable to read repository at http:/​download/​ide/​update_​e4/content.xml.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [this SuiteAnswers article](https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/50195), the correct values are now:

For 2016.2: http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_16_2

For 2017.1: http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_17_1

For 2017.2: http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_17_2

Comment: Oh thanks, not only does the URL in the help guide not work due to some special characters, but it isn't even the correct url! Thanks for this info.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like there are some special characters included in the URL in NetSuite's help guide. If you copy directly from the help guide, the URL won't work.

Here's a working link:

http://system.netsuite.com/download/ide/update_e4